# Swiper Carousel Scrollbar not Accepting an Object as Argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel, swiper.js

I'm working with the [Swiper Carousel](https://idangero.us/swiper/api/) which allows for the option of a scrollbar. I can pass a string that signifies the scrollbar element but if I try to pass an object as per the docs [here](https://idangero.us/swiper/api/#scrollbar), I get an error: `Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined name: TypeError`

I've tracked this to the `set` method here where `e.track` should be an object where each key is a number and the value should be the element (scrollbar):
[image]

Again this works if I set the scrollbar option to a string, but not an object as per the docs. Has anyone seen this before/have any ideas how to get past it? Code below:

This version does not work:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
        loop: false,
        slidesPerView: 'auto',
        slidesPerGroup: 1,
        clickable: true,
        observer: true, 
        observeParents: true,
        speed: 400,
        spaceBetween: 10,
        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
        observer: true,
        scrollbar: {
            el:'.swiper-scrollbar',
            snapOnRelease:true,
            draggable:true,
            hide: false
        },
        breakpoints: {
            768: {
                slidesPerView: 2,
                slidesPerGroup: 2,
                loopedSlides: 2
            }
        }
    })
```

This version does (but I cannot add the extra arguments - e.g. `draggable` & `hide`):

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
        loop: false,
        slidesPerView: 'auto',
        slidesPerGroup: 1,
        clickable: true,
        observer: true, 
        observeParents: true,
        speed: 400,
        spaceBetween: 10,
        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
        observer: true,
        scrollbar: '.swiper-scrollbar',
        breakpoints: {
            768: {
                slidesPerView: 2,
                slidesPerGroup: 2,
                loopedSlides: 2
            }
        }
    })
```

EDIT: As a follow up, I'm not entirely sure which version of Swiper my client is using, but playing around on https://jsfiddle.net/ makes me think they have an outdated version. I've asked them to update and will close this if that is the case